# Can I publish my Windows 10 App on Xbox One?

Tags: win-universal-app, xbox-one

Today, Microsoft is releasing their new Xbox One Experience which is based on Windows 10 OS platform.  In developer conference, Microsoft said the Universal App will run everywhere including Xbox One.

I am looking for more specific documentation on how to do make my Universal App available on Xbox One.

Comment: The xbox one sdk is not released yet, and i think there is no info avaible yet too

Comment: When the SDK for publishing Windows Universal apps on XBox is available, you can sure bet MS is going to have a fairly big press annoucement about it.  BUILD 2016??

Comment: unfortunately, moderator deleted my answer here that has up to date info and kept instead the other answer that has older info. They said I had replied the same at other similar question, but then the other answer says so at their start (that they're a copy of the same answer from other similar question). Not very user-friendly to delete correct answers and leave back obsolete info instead for people to find using Google

Comment: see the most up to date answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34498664/uwp-app-on-xbox

Comment: btw, the moderator suggests that I flag this question as duplicate, but then the other question is referring to this one, so its link to here will then be broken. If the other question is marked as duplicate and deleted, then the correct reply there will be lost and since the moderator deleted the correct reply from here... Don't make StackOverflow yet another over-moderation failure like Wikipedia