# UWP app on Xbox

Tags: windows-10, uwp, xbox

During the events and promotions around Windows 10, I always see that the UWP apps can run on all devices from Microsoft family.

To confirm that, when I am browsing for UWP apps on my browser and I click to see the source code from an app page, I am able to see the following meta data:

```
<meta name="description" content="Download this app from Microsoft Store for Windows Phone 10, Windows 10, Surface HUB, HoloLens, other Windows devices, Xbox. See screenshots, read the latest customer reviews, and compare ratings. " />
```

So why I can't see these apps on my Xbox app store?
I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33677413/can-i-publish-my-windows-10-app-on-xbox-one) stackoverflow answer talking about the Xbox SDK but I don't believe this is the case.

Does anyone have more information about deploying universal apps on Xbox?

Comment: The question you linked is spot on. Right now devs are unable to deploy UWP apps to Xbox (or publish to the store for Xbox). This should be available in the future.

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATES:**

As of March 30, 2016, you can enable your retail-bought Xbox One console to use Dev Mode.

- Start here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xbox-apps/devkit-activation

After Build 2016, I put together a blog post with a video guide (co-hosted with my colleague Dave Voyles), step-by-step instruction slides and a list of clickable links.

- Blog post: http://wakeupandcode.com/build2016-xbox/
- Video on Ch9: https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/GameDevWithShahed/build2016-xbox

**Original Post:**

Currently, UWP is expected to be available on Xbox One in 2016.

Below is a snippet from the ID@Xbox FAQ section that mentions the timeline for UWP on Xbox One and the ability to use retail consoles as dev kits. Note that UWP on Xbox One is in *addition* to the current ID@Xbox program, via which qualified developers have been getting up to 2 free dev kits for approved concepts.

> ### What are the criteria for receiving Xbox One developer kits?
>
> Developers with an approved concept for Xbox One will receive two dev kits, free of charge. Developers creating Universal Windows Apps for Xbox One will be able to test them using retail Xbox Ones starting after the second half of 2015.
>
> ### Can I use my retail Xbox One as a developer kit?
>
> Not yet. For developers working on Universal Windows Apps, you'll be able to test your games on a retail Xbox One sometime after the second half of 2015. Selling UWAs on Xbox One will come in 2016.

Source: General FAQs section of http://www.xbox.com/developers/ID

FYI, UWA = Universal Windows Apps aka UWP = Universal Windows Platform

Answer (score 2):

At Build 2016 Microsoft announced an app that switches back and forth from developer mode a retail Xbox One.

Can join the preview program they have set up for that, but need to unregister from previous preview program if you had such on your console.

Publishing to the Store is not yet available. Xbox Store is to be unified with Windows Store (Phone store already has been)

FAQ:
http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-one/apps/developer-mode-activation-app-faq
and
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xbox-apps/frequently-asked-questions

Also see:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/astebner/2016/03/30/uwp-apps-on-xbox-one-developer-preview-now-available/
and
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xbox-apps/index

Answer (score 0):

Not ready yet. But this is the plan :) Xbox One just been updated to run on Windows 10. Next step is now to open the store for Universal Application. No announcement has been done on this last point at the moment.